# not work sso RHEL APCHE 2.2.15 with auth_kerb_module + AD MS WIN 2012

Tags: linux, apache, single-sign-on, rhel

good afternoon
SSO does not work (client IE 9, FireFox 38)

error.httpd.log

```
[Sun Feb 15 10:06:02 2015] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1944): [client 172.20.204.231] kerb_authenticate_user entered with user (NULL) and auth_type Kerberos
[Sun Feb 15 10:06:02 2015] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1944): [client 172.20.204.231] kerb_authenticate_user entered with user (NULL) and auth_type Kerberos
[Sun Feb 15 10:06:02 2015] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1279): [client 172.20.204.231] Acquiring creds for HTTP/itsm-dev@TEST.DOMAIN.COM.UA
[Sun Feb 15 10:06:02 2015] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1698): [client 172.20.204.231] Verifying client data using KRB5 GSS-API
[Sun Feb 15 10:06:02 2015] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1714): [client 172.20.204.231] Client didn't delegate us their credential
[Sun Feb 15 10:06:02 2015] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1742): [client 172.20.204.231] Warning: received token seems to be NTLM, which isn't supported by the Kerberos module. Check your IE configuration.
[Sun Feb 15 10:06:02 2015] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1139): [client 172.20.204.231] GSS-API major_status:00070000, minor_status:00000000
[Sun Feb 15 10:06:02 2015] [error] [client 172.20.204.231] gss_accept_sec_context() failed: No credentials were supplied, or the credentials were unavailable or inaccessible (, Unknown error)

export KRB5_TRACE=/dev/stdout
 kinit -V -k -t /etc/krb5.keytab -p HTTP/itsmproxy.test.domain.com.ua@test.domain.com.ua
Using default cache: /tmp/krb5cc_0
Using principal: HTTP/itsmproxy.test.domain.com.ua@test.domain.com.ua
Using keytab: /etc/krb5.keytab
[16729] 1424007693.340272: Getting initial credentials for HTTP/itsmproxy.test.domain.com.ua@test.domain.com.ua
[16729] 1424007693.342682: Looked up etypes in keytab: (empty
[16729] 1424007693.342729: Getting initial credentials for HTTP/itsmproxy.test.domain.com.ua@test.domain.com.ua
[16729] 1424007693.342780: Looked up etypes in keytab: (empty
kinit: Keytab contains no suitable keys for HTTP/itsmproxy.test.domain.com.ua@test.domain.com.ua while getting initial credentials

klist -kte /etc/krb5.keytab2
Keytab name: FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab2

KVNO Timestamp         Principal
---- ----------------- --------------------------------------------------------

5 01/01/70 03:00:00 HTTP/itsm-dev@TEST.DOMAIN.COM.UA (arcfour-hmac)
```

where could be the problem?

Comment: You need to be clear about what you're trying to do and what the problem is. At the moment your question is just a massive block of log text, not a question.

Comment: SSO does not work. Why is not known. worried log entry: Warning: received token seems to be NTLM, which isn't supported by the Kerberos module. Check your IE configuration.

Comment: Although kvno says that everything is fine:  kvno HTTP/itsm-dev@TEST.DOMAIN.COM.UA
HTTP/itsm-dev@TEST.DOMAIN.COM.UA: kvno = 5

Answer (score 0):

On Linux side you are using mod_auth_kerb which supports Kerberos authentication but your client sends NTLMSSP. This is unsupported.

If you want to have NTLMSSP working, you'd better to use mod_auth_gssapi and GSSAPI NTLMSSP modules from https://github.com/simo5/mod_auth_gssapi and https://fedorahosted.org/gss-ntlmssp/

Comment: This module requires a newer httpd and krb5 and they are not in the repository RHEL 6.4